# direct proof of an identity regarding certain symmetry of integer partitions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Suppose $(a_1,\ldots, a_k)$ is an integer partition of $n$, and $(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$ is a rearrangement of the $a$-sequence. Prove the following identity (preferably combinatorially):
$$
\sum_{j_2+\cdots+j_k=l,\atop l\geq 0, \, a_t>j_t\geq 0} \quad\frac{(-1)^l l!}{(a_1+l+1)_{l+1}} {a_2\choose j_2}\cdots {a_k \choose j_k}=\sum_{j_2+\cdots+j_k=l,\atop l\geq 0, \, b_t>j_t\geq 0} \quad\frac{(-1)^l l!}{(b_1+l+1)_{l+1}} {b_2\choose j_2}\cdots {b_k \choose j_k},
$$
where $(x)_k$ is the falling factorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant $j_t\leq a_t$ (not $j_t<a_t$).

It's sufficient to prove that for any analytic function $f(x)$, the function
$$F(a_1,a_2) := \sum_{l\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^{a_2} \frac{(-1)^ll!}{(a_1+l+1)_{l+1}} \binom{a_2}{j} [x^{l-j}]\ f(x)$$
is symmetric, i.e. $F(a_1,a_2) = F(a_2,a_1)$.

Using the property of [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), we have

\begin{split}
F(a_1,a_2) &=\sum_{l\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^ll!}{(a_1+l+1)_{l+1}} [x^l]\ (1+x)^{a_2}f(x) \\
&=\sum_{l\geq 0} (-1)^l \int_0^1 t^l (1-t)^{a_1} {\rm d}t\ [x^l]\ (1+x)^{a_2}f(x)\\
&=\int_0^1 (1-t)^{a_1} (1-t)^{a_2} f(-t) {\rm d}t,
\end{split}
which is clearly symmetric.

Comment: Thanks Max! Actually, it has to be $j_t < a_t$, otherwise the identity does not hold. This can be checked, for instance, using the integer partition $(2,1)$.

Comment: @rickychen: I do not quite follow. When $k=2$, the sum over $j_2=l\leq a_2$ gives $\frac{1}{a_1+a_2+1}$, which is symmetric.

Comment: Let me proceed carefully, assuming $j_2 \leq a_2$. For $(2,1)$, the left-hand side gives $$\frac{(-1)^0 0!}{(2+0+1)_1}{1\choose 0}+ \frac{(-1)^1 1!}{(2+1+1)_2}{1\choose 1}$$, while for $(1,2)$, the right-hand side gives $$\frac{(-1)^0 0!}{(1+0+1)_1} {2\choose 0} +\frac{(-1)^1 1!}{(1+1+1)_2}{2\choose 1} +\frac{(-1)^2 2!}{(1+2+1)_3}{2\choose 2}$$. They are not equal! But, if we assume $j_2<a_2$, then they are equal.

Comment: please see my detailed computation above, one gives $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{12}$, the other gives $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{24}$. BTW, why I could not see "@max" that I put at the very beginning.

Comment: You have a numerical error in the second term of the second sum. It should be $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{6} + \frac{2}{24} = \frac{1}{4}$, which matches the first sum and the formula $\frac1{a_1+a_2+1}$.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for the error. I am still having trouble to follow your proof, it seems you have proved a much stronger statement, that is, $f(x)$ could be arbitrary. Could you elaborate more on (1) why it is sufficient to show $F$ is symmetric? (2) in your computation, how did you change the $x$ into $t$ in the last step? thanks.

Comment: Without loss of generality we may assume that $a_3=b_3$, $a_4=b_4$ etc., while $(a_1,a_2)=(b_2,b_1)$. Then if you plug $f(x) = (1+x)^{a_3} (1+x)^{a_4} \dots (1+x)^{a_k}$ into my formula, you'll get yours. But my statement is indeed more general since $f(x)$ can be arbitrary analytic one.

Comment: As for the change from $x$ to $t$, one needs to recognize that $\sum_{l\geq 0} (-t)^l [x^l]\ G(x)$ (for any function $G$) corresponds to substitution of $x=-t$ into $G(x)$, that is, this sum equals $G(-t)$,